# I can't translate text in my plugin using a .mo file, load_plugin_textdomain() function is always false

Tags: translation

I create a plugin just for testing

```
/**
 * @package SurveyPlugin
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Survey Plugin
Plugin URI: http:marcogomesweb.com
Description: This is survey
Author: NodeLondon
Version: 1.0
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: survey-plugin
*/

function get_dummy_text() {
    $text = [
        __( 'city hotels' , 'survey-plugin' )
    ];
    return $text[0];
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'show_dummy_text');

function show_dummy_text(){
    $text = get_dummy_text();
    global $locale;
    echo "<br>". $locale . "<br>";
    echo "<p id='wp-admin-motivation'>$text</p>";
}


add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wan_loaded_textdomain');


function wan_loaded_textdomain(){

     $loadfiles = load_plugin_textdomain('survey-plugin', false, 
     dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );

     plugin_basename( __FILE__ ). '/languages/' );



     var_dump($loadfiles); // is always false


}
```

I install Poedit I create a .mo file `survey-plugi-es_ES.mo`
in `/plugins/survey-plugin/languages/`

[image]

**survey-plugi-es_ES.mo**

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Survey Plugin\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2019-03-15 14:16+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2019-03-15 14:16+0000\n"
"Language-Team: Marcogomesr\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.2.1\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: __\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language: es\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-1: survey-plugin.php\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPathExcluded-0: src\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPathExcluded-1: dist\n"

#: survey-plugin.php:79
msgid "city hotels"
msgstr "ciudad"
```

and this is what echo out

[image]

after changing the languages in the `settings / site languages`
still showing the same,

I'm following this t[utorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6lewCGXbTo&list=PLdQJXLDS_nIWkrTmseyHHG8QvP1St4Pia&index=2) but still having no idea why

Answer (score 2):

*(Revised answer)*

The simple answer is because WordPress could not find the MO file, despite the file itself exists (in the plugin's `languages` directory).

And here's why: *The MO file needs to be named following this format: `{text-domain}-{locale}.mo`, and `{text-domain}-{locale}.po` for the PO file.* See [Loading Text Domain](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#loading-text-domain) for further information.

So you're trying to load the MO file for the `survey-plugin` domain:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'survey-plugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' )
```

Hence for the `es_ES` locale (Español),

- The MO file name has to be `survey-plugin-es_ES.mo`.
- The PO file name has to be `survey-plugin-es_ES.po`.

*And I think you may not be aware that the POT (translation template) file needs be named like so: `{text-domain}.pot`?* E.g. `survey-plugin.pot` in your case.

Or was the `survey-plugi` just a typo? :)

But even if so, I hope this answer helps (other developers/readers).